# Group MongoDB collection by 5 fields where the collection has more than 5 million records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The Mongo query I used, which is working on smaller chunk of data is

```
var map = function () {
    emit({item:this.item, outlet:this.outlet, batch:this.batch, item_name:this.item_name, outlet_name:this.outlet_name}, {count:1,_id:this._id});
}

var reduce = function(k, values) {
    var result = {count: 0,_id:[]};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.count += value.count;
        result._id.push(value._id);
    });
    return result;
}

db.ItemMovementSummary.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: { replace : "multi_result"}})
db.multi_result.find({'value.count' : {$gte : 2}})
```

The error mongo is giving me is-

> "message" : "map reduce failed:MongoError: Exceeded depth limit of 150
>   when converting js object to BSON. Do you have a cycle?",
>   "code" : 17279

Is there any way to solve this, I did try to group them initially which failed with error

> Plan executor error during group command :: caused by :: group() can't
>   handle more than 20000 unique keys

Answer (score 0):

The db.collection.group() method does not work with sharded clusters. Use the aggregation framework or map-reduce in sharded environments.

The result set must fit within the maximum BSON document size.

In version 2.2, the returned array can contain at most 20,000 elements; i.e. at most 20,000 unique groupings. For group by operations that results in more than 20,000 unique groupings, use mapReduce. Previous versions had a limit of 10,000 elements.

http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/MongoDB.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/index.html#dbcmd.mapReduce